# Populating ViewModel from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a SPA that queries the AdventureWorks2012 database and populates a strongly typed table based on a datetime range using Jquery ui datepicker.

The issue I'm experiencing is it returns all of the same duplicate record.

[Duplicate Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcC46.png)

Thanks for the help!

_Layout View code:

```
 <div>
    <h2>Pick a date range:</h2>
    <form action='@Url.Action("GetOrders","Home")' method="post">
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="startDate">
    <label for="to">To</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="endDate">
    <input type='submit' value='Set Range' />
    </form>
 </div>

$( function() {
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
  from = $( "#from" )
    .datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on( "change", function() {
      to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
    }),
  to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3
  })
  .on( "change", function() {
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
  });

function getDate( element ) {
  var date;
  try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
  } catch( error ) {
    date = null;
  }

  return date;
}});
```

GetOrders.cshtml Code:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<ApexAssignment.ViewModels.OrderViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.Store
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.Customer
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.AccountNumber
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.InvoiceNumber
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.CustomerPO
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.OrderDate
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.DueDate
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.InvoiceTotal
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.ProductNumber
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.Quantity
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
            @item.UnitNet
        </td>
</tr>
}
```

Controller Method Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetOrders(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var model = (from p in db.People
                     from pd in db.Products
                     from so in db.SalesOrderDetails
                     from sh in db.SalesOrderHeaders
                     where sh.OrderDate > startDate && sh.OrderDate < endDate
                     from s in db.Stores
                     from c in db.Customers
                     select new OrderViewModel()
                     {
                         AccountNumber = sh.AccountNumber,
                         Customer = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                         Store = s.Name,
                         ProductNumber = pd.ProductNumber,
                         DueDate = sh.DueDate,
                         CustomerPO = sh.PurchaseOrderNumber,
                         Quantity = so.OrderQty,
                         InvoiceNumber = sh.SalesOrderNumber,
                         UnitNet = so.UnitPrice,
                         InvoiceTotal = sh.TotalDue,
                         OrderDate = sh.OrderDate
                     });

        return View(model.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: you need to add joins to your linq

Comment: I think it's kind of cross join try use inner join or left join by using join statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var model = db.SalesOrderDetails
    .Where(e => e.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate > startDate)
    .Where(e => e.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate < endDate)
    .Join(db.Products, order => order.ProductID, 
        product => product.ProductID, (order, product) => new
        {
            Quantity = order.OrderQty,
            UnitNet = order.UnitPrice,
            DueDate = order.SalesOrderHeader.DueDate,
            CustomerPO = order.SalesOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber,
            InvoiceNumber = order.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNumber,
            InvoiceTotal = order.SalesOrderHeader.TotalDue,
            OrderDate = order.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate,
            AccountNumber = order.SalesOrderHeader.AccountNumber,
            Store = order.SalesOrderHeader.Customer.Store.Name,
            Customer = order.SalesOrderHeader.Customer.Person.FirstName + " " +
                        order.SalesOrderHeader.Customer.Person.LastName,
            ProductNumber = product.ProductNumber
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  So after new keyword I would do OrderViewModel()?